# accessing a specific view from onclick listener inside getView of customer adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, custom-adapter

I want the onclick method to communicate with the other views in my layout. I am getting a NullPointerException when attempting to do so. I think I may be doing it wrong.

My `getView` method is below:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    final int p =position;
    if (v == null) {
       LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       v = vi.inflate(R.layout.menuitemrow, null);
       holder = new ViewHolder();
       holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.MIR_itemImage);holder.image.setTag(position);
       holder.itemName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.MIR_itemName);holder.itemName.setTag(position);
       holder.itemPrice = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.MIR_itemPrice);holder.itemPrice.setTag(position);
       holder.itemOther = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.MIR_itemOther);holder.itemOther.setTag(position);
       holder.details = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.MIR_detailsbtn);holder.details.setTag(position);
       holder.qAdd = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.MIR_qaddbtn);holder.qAdd.setTag(position);
       v.setTag(holder);
    } else 
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    MenuItemDetail mid = _data.get(position);
    holder.image.setImageResource(mid.icon);
    holder.itemName.setText(mid.itemName);
    holder.itemPrice.setText("Price: $"+mid.itemPrice);
    holder.itemOther.setText(mid.itemOther);
    //set click listeners
    holder.details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            m =_data.get(p);
            s = m.getItemName();
            Toast.makeText(_c, "clicked details"+p+" "+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    holder.qAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(_c, "clicked quick add "+p, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            TextView btnUpdate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.CBV_textview2);
            //btnUpdate.setTag(1);
            //btnUpdate.setText(btnUpdate.getTag().toString());
            btnUpdate.setText("b");
        }
    });


    return v;
}
```

as you can see I am just assigning a number to the `getTag` just to pass it to the `setText` method. I have tried it commenting out the set and get, using just a `String`.

the problematic line is `btnUpdate.setText("b");`

Any ideas?

to summarize I am trying to access a `TextView` of a custom `Button` inside of a custom `ListView` from its customer adapter's `getView` method.

UPDATE for comment:

This is a Custom Listview being displayed with other buttons. I want the listview item (a button that is part of the custom `ListView`) when it is click to update the textview of a custom button I created that is displayed in the same acitivity as the custom list view.

The Layout is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/MI_backbutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/back_list_categories"
    android:textSize="@dimen/FontSize8" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/menuList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/generalbutton" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/MI_checkorder"
        style="android:buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        layout="@layout/custombtnview"
        android:background="@style/AppTheme"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the view I am referencing to get the Textview, the textview is not there. What is in that view is the `MI_checkorder`. I was thinking maybe this is why I am getting the `NullPointerException` for my `btnUpdate`. the textveiw `CBV_textview2` is part of the view I created as a button(`MI_checkorder`).

I now have the button but I am unable to get the change to show on the UI. Here is the code I added:

```
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(_c, "clicked quick add "+p, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            TextView btnUpdate = (TextView) inflateToEdit(_c, v).findViewById(R.id.CBV_textview2);
            //btnUpdate.setTag(1);
            //btnUpdate.setText(btnUpdate.getTag().toString());
            btnUpdate.setText("b");
        }
```

and this is the method I created in the custom adapter class.

```
    public View inflateToEdit(Context c, View view){
    View vw = view;
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    return vi.inflate(R.layout.custombtnview, null);
}
```

It is updating the button's text but it is not showing on the UI. I do not think i can update the UI from this point in the code. I think I need to do it from the activity.

Comment: Is this in a ListView, or something? Please tell us a bit more. Usually you can just assign an OnItemClickListener to an AdapterView (Like a ListView holding an array adapter) that would make this process a whole lot simpler, if I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: I updated the Question to be more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because *findViewById* called on a view looks for the child view of the given view.

[findViewById doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29)

"Look for a child view with the given id. If this view has the given id, return this view."

From what I can see, CBV_textview2 is contained in the layout of the activity. 
So, what you can do is to pass the activity to the adapter's constructor (I see you already have a _c member variable which I suppose is a Context, OR directly pass the CBV_textview2 itself (calling findViewById in the containing activty).

In both cases, you need to call the activity's findViewById which
"Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle)."

```
public class YourAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private final Context context;
  // blahblahblah
  private final TextView mYourTextView;

 public YourAdapter(Context context, String[] values, TextView btnUpdate) {
     super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
     this.context = context;
     this.values = values;
     mYourTextView = btnUpdate;
 }

 ....

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(_c, "clicked quick add "+p, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //mYourTextView.setTag(1);
        //mYourTextView.setText(btnUpdate.getTag().toString());
        mYourTextView.setText("b");
    }
```

In your activity you should be able to get the TextView before calling the constructor.

Comment: I added: `TextView btnUpdate = (TextView) inflateToEdit(_c, v).findViewById(R.id.CBV_textview2);` which allows me to inflate and I now have the textview. But I cannot update from in here. I am assuming I do not have access to the UI thread from there. how can I send that up the tunnel and maybe have it call a method of the activity to update it.

Comment: The onClick callback is executed inside the ui thread. Why you can't update from there? And what is inflateToEdit method? The button should have been already inflated in your activity's setContentView.

Comment: That's because you are inflating a NEW custombtnview. You need to reference the one of your activity. Can't you pass it it your adapter's constructor?

Comment: i do but when I try `findViewById` it returns a null reference and I get the exception. I do not know why this line: `TextView btnUpdate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.CBV_textview2);` does not work. so thats when I changed the code to what you just saw. I will remove that as it makes sense that I am creating a NEW custombtnview. I just thought that because I had to do it in the get view for the custom row in my list view that I had to do it for that since it was a custom view button I created.

Comment: Just have findViewById in your activity's onCreate and pass the TextView to the adapter's constructor.

Comment: Thanks a ton! that worked perfectly. Is there a way that I can pass my include to the adapter so I have access to all of its parts and can update them independently?

Comment: Don't think so. What you can do is to pass the activity instead of the view itself and call findviewbyid on the activity reference.

Comment: that sounds perfect!!! how do I pass the activity. I already pass the context to the adapter.

Comment: Yes as a paremeter...like this?
`public MenuItemAdapter(..., Context c, Activity a){`
and what do I put from my activity. I know this is the context. what do I say if my activity class is cActivity for example when contructing the adapter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25188/discussion-between-mark-and-fedepaol)